# Watchkit communication error when iPhone app not loaded

Tags: ios, watchkit

When trying to send a message from my app's watch extension delegate to the companion iPhone app, an error is raised (WCErrorCodeDeliveryFailed).

The situation is:

- using simulator or devices (iOS 10.1 WatchOS 2)
- iPhone app not loaded in memory (neither foreground nor background)
- in Watch extension delegate `awakeWithContext` method, session is activated
- in Watch extension delegate `willActivate` method a message is sent to iPhone app

`if ([self.watchSession isReachable]){
    NSDictionary *applicationDict = @{@"request":@"Status"};
    [self.watchSession sendMessage:applicationDict replyHandler:nil errorHandler:nil];
}`

This gives an error message: `[WCSession _onqueue_notifyOfMessageError:withErrorHandler:] errorHandler: NO with WCErrorCodeDeliveryFailed`

Thus, this message send the iPhone app in background...

any idea? Thanks

Comment: Where do  you see this message?  You aren't specifying an error handler

Comment: In the debugger window (XCode)

Comment: I would ignore that; Supply an error handler to `sendMessage` and see if you are getting an *actual* error.

Comment: I tried, but couldn't display the error, not sure that's because there is not actual error. Thanks for help